# Enumerating Network Resources WNetOpenEnum returning ERROR_BAD_NETPATH(error 53) After a Long Time

Tags: windows, winapi, networking

I am trying to get all the shared PCs using the code present at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385341(v=vs.85).aspx

The problem I am facing is that the method `WNetOpenEnum` is taking huge amount of time while opening "Microsoft Windows Network" resource and returning the error `ERROR_BAD_NETPATH`.

I have noticed that the Windows explorer is able to access the shared PCs and their folders.

I also have noticed that `WNetConnectionDialog` also working fine.
If I select Browse button,its able to refresh the net connections and able to see the shared PCs and their folders.

Strangely the code present works fine for Point to Point connection.

1. Can some one help me in solving this issue?
2. Also can some one suggest me how to refresh the shared resources using windows API?
3. Are there any methods in QT/boost which can find shared PCS?